# Memory Exception on Excel Fuzzy Lookup Add In

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, memory, lookup

I have two tables of data with 5 columns - Name, Phone Number, Email Address, Post Code and Order Time.  Both tables have around 10,000 rows. I need there to be an exact match on Name, Phone Number, Email Address and Post Code and a fuzzy match on order time - as the order times can be off from a few seconds to a few minutes in both sets of data. I want to be able to reconcile orders on both sets of data allowing for a time window.

I have created two sets of tables for both datasets and ran the fuzzy lookup with 5 separate matching columns - 4 of them exact matches on Name, Phone Number, Email Address and Post Code and a default fuzzy match on the Order Time. However when I run the fuzzy lookup I get a memory timeout error at about 300 rows. Does anyone know how I could resolve this? I have a 8gb memory machine but I’m not sure if increasing the memory will fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Hi! I'm using Excel 365

Comment: You can explore ways to use fuzzy matching via Merge through Power Query:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/fuzzy-match-support-for-get-transform-power-query-ffdd5082-c0c8-4c8e-a794-bd3962b90649

(I suspect your use case makes this not an option). Or review the options here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42839412/excel-memory-limit-while-using-fuzzy-lookup

Comment: Thanks! I've looked into Power Query and it doesn't seem applicable to this use case - as you thought. I looked into the topic discussed in the link above and im doing everything suggested but still i get the timeout.